# pass data from jQuery to php

Tags: php, jquery, wamp

I have 4 buttons and I want to pass the name of the pressed one to a PHP script. Note that the buttons toggle a popover.

```
$("[data-toggle=popover_edit]").click(function () {
    var btn_edit_name = $(this).attr('name');
    var data = { cat: btn_edit_name };
    $.post('task.php', data, function(returnedData) {
        // do something here with the returnedData
        alert(returnedData);
    });  
});
```

I tried this too but it's not working either:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover_edit]").click(function () {
    var datasend = 'cat=' + $(this).attr('name') ;
    $.ajax({
        url: "task.php" ,
        data: datasend,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function(retour) {}
    });
});
```

I'm trying to catch the data here. task.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST['cat'])):
    // set or update???
    $data = $user->get_aptitude($_SESSION['username'], $_POST['cat']);

    //set
    if ($data == null):
        $err = $user->set_jeune_aptitude($_SESSION['username'], $contenu, $_POST['cat']);

    //update
    else:
        $err = $user->update_aptitude($_SESSION['username'], $contenu, $_POST['cat']);
    endif;
```

And this is the code of the button.it's working and i already checked if the value i'm passing is the right one:

```
echo '<a class="list-group-item active">Artistiques<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover_edit" id="edit_btn"  name="art"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit "></i></button>   </a>';
```

Note: I'm working with WAMP.

Comment: Your jQuery code should work. Have you checked the console, or network monitor tab for errors?

Comment: Does the ajax call work outside of a click event, if you were to hard-code it to get called with data being `"cat=username"` or whatever the name attribute of the button would be?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML structure of the button?

Comment: @3abqari this is the code.the button is working normal and i already checked if the value i'm passing is the right one:
`code`
 echo '<a class="list-group-item active">Artistiques
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover_edit" id="edit_btn"  name="art"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit "></i></button>   </a>';`code`

Comment: Your button's type is a submit.  Are you sure it doesn't submit the form resulting in a page refresh, separate than the ajax call?

Comment: try to have the click event function be like this `function(event)`, and then inside that function body, add this line at the beginning: `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: It is!!the button belong to a popover with a form!!but i want to pass the name of the button clicked separtly.
I already tried to pass the value by a hidden input but failed.

Comment: Can you please verify if it's at least reaching the task.php page?  And if so, can you find out what gets posted to the page? Use `print_r($_POST);` and return it in the ajax success function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it! I was passing the value by clicking on button 1, this one opens a popover with a form.
I just catch the $_post and put it in a var for later (after the treatment of the form)

Thank you for the help.